# When saving XML file with XElement, alignment in file changes as well, how to avoid?

Tags: c#, xml, whitespace, xelement

I am using

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(filepath);
```

to load XML file, then finding things that I need.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> commands = from command in MyCommands
                                 where (string) command.Attribute("Number") == Number
                                 select command;

foreach (XElement command in commands)
{
     command.SetAttributeValue("Group", GroupFound);
}
```

When I am done with my changes, I save the file with the following code.

```
root.Save(filepath);
```

When file is saved, all the lines in my XML file are affected. Visual Studio aligns all the lines by default, but I need to save the original file format.

I cannot alter any part of the document, except the Group attribute values.

```
command.SetAttributeValue("Group") attributes.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would need to do:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(filepath, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

then do:

```
root.Save(filepath, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

This will preserve your original whitespace through the use of [LoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.loadoptions.aspx) and [SaveOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.saveoptions.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The information you're looking to preserve is lost to begin in the XDocument.

XDocument doesn't care if your elements had tabs or spaces on the line in front of them and if there are multiple whitespaces between attributes etc. If you want to rely on the Save() method you have to give up the idea you can preserve formatting.

To preserve formatting you'll need to add custom processing and figure out where precisely to make changes. Alternatively you may be able to adjust your save options to match the formatting you have if your XML is coming from a machine and not human edited

Comment: my XML file has 10000 lines, what is the best way ? not sure that custom formatting is an option

Comment: I don't know what is it you're trying to achieve - are you building an XML editor or are you trying to exactly match some web service output? Is the source format reliable and consistent or can it change all the time (or even once)? Are you looking to preserve *all* the formatting, such as spaces between attributes or not?

Comment: answer above is what I was looking for, to leave whitespaces but do not touch alignment