# How to add XComment on same line as an XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Desired XML output:

```
<role>1</role> <!-- Role: Master -->
```

If I do this:

```
string roleId = "1";
xRoot.Add(XElement("role", roleId));
string roleComment = string.Format("Role: {0}", roleMap[roleId]);
XComment xRoleComment = new XComment(roleComment);
xRoot.Add(xRoleComment);
```

I get this (notice comment on next line):

```
<role>1</role>
<!-- Role: Master -->
```

Comment: Consider to change "desired XML output" to be: `<role>Master</role>` and remove whole issue with strangely placed comment...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Alternatively: `<role id="1">Master</role>`

Comment: XML doesn't actually have "lines", per se. I'm not sure you can do it this way. You may need to add your own explicit space between the element and the comment, then save while preserving whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is in the `SaveOptions` for the xml file. Look here for more: [When saving XML file with XElement, alignment in file changes as well, how to avoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155516/when-saving-xml-file-with-xelement-alignment-in-file-changes-as-well-how-to-av)

But this looks like it will disable all formatting. Instead, you might consider putting the comment first, which would be more aligned with how comments usually appear - before the line they are commenting on instead of after.

Comment: Looks like there's no way to do it, so, comment-first is the way to go.  I didn't like the in-line comment idea anyway, it was something someone else had done who was just writing the XML out as text strings, and, I was just trying to match for a diff.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting is up to the Xml standard. Except by totally disabling formatting, you can't put two different tags side by side, be it a comment tag. The exception is for empty elements :

```
<MyElement></MyElement>
```

is valid, but

```
</MyElement><MyOtherElement></MyOtherElement>
```

is not considered proper formatting.

Comment: Not sure what you refer to, but [Xml standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-well-formed) does not define nor require any formatting...

Comment: Indeed you are right, the standard doesn't define formatting. However, all the samples and examples I found enforced this implicit rule.